# Unity Animated Player Character Rotation Glitch

Tags: unity, camera, rotation, mecanim, bug

I was wondering if anyone experienced this issue in Unity with Mecanim-animated characters ...

I have an animated player character with a third-person camera control (Game Camera from the asset store, even though I think it isn't really related) and if the character is standing at the default y-rotation angle I can orbit around her with the camera and she will always face the same direction, as it should be.

But if the character stands with an arbitrary other transform y-rotation (for example 90.0001 or 180, etc.) and I orbit around the character, the character's Y rotation is ever so often randomly changed.

I don't know what changes the Y rotation. Game Camera doesn't touch it as long as I don't move the character so I suppose it is related to Mecanim, even though i'm not sure about that either.

I was hoping somebody has more familiarity with this issue and know what causes this. This glitch is definitely a problem in gameplay.

Answer (score 2):

Some values of Mechanim animations are absolute. Then you rotate or move your character, actual values changes, but animations still use old hard-coded values in wolrd-space coordinates.
You should try to put your character into empty parent object. Animate character itself, but rotate and move the parent.